# Looping rows and column Dynamic Selection Division Issue

Tags: php, mysql

My problem is that my system needs to output the total number of tables available from a particular shop by the help of MySQL. As I have discovered that, $seat = 11 and 11 cannot be exactly divided by 3 it only outputs only 10 seats. Any help will be helpful.

```
<?php
    $cols = 5;
    $rows = round($seat / $cols);
    $num = 1;

    //echo "<table border='1'>";
    for ($tr = 1; $tr <= $rows; $tr++) {

        echo "<div class='seatRow'>";
        echo "<div class='seatRowNumber'>";
        echo "</div>";

        for ($td = 1; $td <= $cols; $td++) {
            //echo "<td>row: ".$tr." column: ".$td."</td>";
            echo "<div id='_$num' role='checkbox' value='45' aria-checked='false' focusable='true' tabindex='-1' class=' seatNumber '>" . $num++ . "";
            echo "</div>";
        }
        echo "</div>";
    }

    //echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: If it was me, I'd start with the SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `ceil()` instead of `round()` and break the second loop if you have reached the number of seats:

```
<?php
    $seat = 11;
    $cols = 5;
    $rows = ceil($seat / $cols); // <-- use ceil()
    $num = 1;

    //echo "<table border='1'>";
    for ($tr = 1; $tr <= $rows; $tr++) {

        echo "<div class='seatRow'>";
        echo "<div class='seatRowNumber'>";
        echo "</div>";

        for ($td = 1; $td <= $cols; $td++) {
            if($num > $seat) break; //<-- break the loop if you reach number of seats
            //echo "<td>row: ".$tr." column: ".$td."</td>";
            echo "<div id='_$num' role='checkbox' value='45' aria-checked='false' focusable='true' tabindex='-1' class=' seatNumber '>" . $num++ . "";
            echo "</div>";
        }
        echo "</div>";
    }

    //echo "</table>";
?>
```

Output:

```
<div class="seatRow">
    <div class="seatRowNumber"></div>
    <div id="_1" role="checkbox" value="45" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class=" seatNumber ">1</div>
    <div id="_2" role="checkbox" value="45" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class=" seatNumber ">2</div>
    <div id="_3" role="checkbox" value="45" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class=" seatNumber ">3</div>
    <div id="_4" role="checkbox" value="45" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class=" seatNumber ">4</div>
    <div id="_5" role="checkbox" value="45" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class=" seatNumber ">5</div>
</div>
<div class="seatRow">
    <div class="seatRowNumber"></div>
    <div id="_6" role="checkbox" value="45" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class=" seatNumber ">6</div>
    <div id="_7" role="checkbox" value="45" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class=" seatNumber ">7</div>
    <div id="_8" role="checkbox" value="45" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class=" seatNumber ">8</div>
    <div id="_9" role="checkbox" value="45" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class=" seatNumber ">9</div>
    <div id="_10" role="checkbox" value="45" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class=" seatNumber ">10</div>
</div>
<div class="seatRow">
    <div class="seatRowNumber"></div>
    <div id="_11" role="checkbox" value="45" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class=" seatNumber ">11</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the valuable idea and the code you have provided. It saved me. Thank you again. I will mark it as the correct answer :-p @mitkosoft